# Connecting Raspberry Pi to Android Wear

Tags: bluetooth, android-wear

I have a Raspberry Pi with a Bluetooth Dongle and an Android Wear Device (LG G Watch). How would I connect my G Watch to my Raspberry Pi via Bluetooth? Thanks!

Comment: connect it to do what? act like a phone?